# Round Raster values up to nearest 10 QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, round-function

I have a raster with cell data varying between 0.1 and 156. I want to round the data to the nearest 10, i.e any value between 0.1-10 = 10, 10.1-20 = 20 and so on. Theres lots online about rounding to the nearest decimal, but not to the nearest 10...

I have tried using the raster calculator, GDAL raster calculator and endless other things, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GRASS r.mapcalc.simple to calculate it. You can find it in the Processing Toolbox (GRASS/Raster (r.*)/r.mapcalc.simple).
The formula to get nearest larger 10 is:

```
round((A + 5) / 10) * 10
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. This didnt work for me. Raster is a float32, would this be the problem, and how do i change if so? :)

Comment: Accepted as correct, converted raster points to polygons and applied the same formula.. same same but different. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it with a single band float32 raster (DEM), on Ubuntu with QGIS 3.10.4 and GRASS 7.8.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest version of **QGIS 3.13** (Master/Developer Version) you can use the native `Round raster` algorithm in the Processing toolbox. This algorithm exposes parameters to round to the nearest 10 of the raster values. The algorithm will become available for the general public with the QGIS 3.14 release.